# Apache Drill - MySQL and DATA_READ ERROR: Failure while attempting to read from database

Tags: apache-drill

I installed Apache Drill (version 1.8.0) and configured my MySQL-Plugin as outlined in the documentation: https://drill.apache.org/docs/plugin-configuration-basics/

Everything works out and yes, I am able to test the connection. 
By using

```
select * from myplugin.database.calc_campaigns;
```

I get an output. Surprisingly not for all tables. If I use

```
select * from myplugin.database.campaigns;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: DATA_READ ERROR: Failure while attempting to read from database.

sql SELECT *
FROM `database`.`campaign`
plugin myplugin
Fragment 0:0

[Error Id: 2eaceb16-c09f-41bd-a139-52bc8b1d2da5 on r4c01.pmd.local:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

I have no glue what this error means.

Anybody can help out or got the same error?
Best
Peter

Answer (score 2):

After checking the affected tables I found the problem:

Some tables contain the date "0000-00-00" which is problematic regarding java.sql.Date.

To fix this you should update the MySQL-plugin to

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull